# How can I change the value of a property in a list for just one value when the property value is ()?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list in C# like this where in some rows, one of the fields sometimes has an entry of `"()"`:

I can find these rows like this:

```
var ps = phraseSources.Where(x => x.WatsonMeaning == "()");
```

But how can I change using Linq, all occurrences of "()" in the WatsonMeaning column to "n/a".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `ForEach` LINQ method:

```
list
  .Where(i => i.WatsonMeaning == "()")
  .ToList()
  .ForEach(i => i.WatsonMeaning = "n/a")
```

Comment: out of curiosity, would List.ForEach considered part of Linq ?

Comment: @AnuViswan Yes, it is

Comment: @AnuViswan: No, it's not. It predates LINQ and has nothing to do with querying. Here, it's allocating a new list just to act on the filtered set. That's the antithesis of LINQ. LINQ would use an iterator on the predicate without allocating the list, making the `ForEach` method unavailable. A `foreach` loop would be the LINQ way to do it. This answer works, but don't confuse the `ForEach` part with LINQ.

Comment: @madreflection _A `foreach` loop would be the LINQ way to do it_ - how exactly would that be _LINQ way_? Are you referring to the fact that when using `foreach` a new list would not be created? If yes, using `foreach` still doesn't have anything to do with LINQ, does it?

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ: Yes, I was, and you are correct. What I meant was simply that a `foreach` loop is a *natural consequence* of using "pure" LINQ rather than creating a throwaway list just to do the iteration.

Comment: ["foreach" vs. "ForEach"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
static void Test()
{
  var phraseSources = new List<A>();
  phraseSources.Add(new A { WatsonMeaning = "()" });
  phraseSources.Add(new A { WatsonMeaning = "text1" });
  phraseSources.Add(new A { WatsonMeaning = "()" });
  phraseSources.Add(new A { WatsonMeaning = "text2" });
  phraseSources.Add(new A { WatsonMeaning = "text3" });

  phraseSources.Where(x => x.WatsonMeaning == "()")
               .ToList()
               .ForEach(x => x.WatsonMeaning = "n/a");

  foreach ( var item in phraseSources )
    Console.WriteLine(item.WatsonMeaning);
}

class A
{
  public string WatsonMeaning;
}
```